# How do I change the default value of a dropdown field based on a button in Power Apps?

Tags: user-defined-functions, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

On my home screen in Powerapps, I have 8 buttons. Each button states a category. What I want is that by selecting a certain button it makes the value automatically be filled in on the dropdown field of categories on the next page.

[image][image]

I have already added this code to the on select function of the buttons: Navigate(Screen4);; Set(value; "Buttonname"). I have also set the default value of the category field to this value. But nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using drop down control or combo box control? What is the formula used for drop down items default value?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to populate the "DefaultSelectedItems" property in your ComboBox and the way you populate will depend on how the ***Record***  of your ComboBox looks like.

It's common that you will have to do something like this for the "DefaultSelectedItems":

```
DefaultSelectedItems: {Value:variable} //in your case variable will be value
```